# How to convert XML to CSV using the correct StyleSheet if there are child nodes

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

I am having an issue creating an `.xsl` file for the following `xml` code below. I want to turn it into a `csv` file

```
XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<info infoID="Info_ABC">
  <descriptions>
    <description descriptionId="1" descriptionName="Test1">
      <functions>
        <function functionId="123">
          <programs>
            <program programName="Xml2Csv">
              <objects>
                <object objectId="111" objectLevel="Green" status="Yes"/>
                <object objectId="222" objectLevel="Blue" status="No"/>
                <object objectId="333" objectLevel="Red" status="Maybe"/>
              </objects> 
              <objects2>
                <object objectId="444" objectLevel="Yellow" status="Yes"/>
                <object objectId="555" objectLevel="Purple" status="Yes"/>
              </objects2>
            </program>
          </programs>
        </function>
        <function functionId="456">
          <programs>
            <program programName="Xml5Csv">
              <objects>
                <object objectId="666" objectLevel="Green" status="Yes"/>
                <object objectId="777" objectLevel="Blue" status="No"/>
                <object objectId="888" objectLevel="Red" status="Maybe"/>
              </objects> 
              <objects2>
                <object objectId="999" objectLevel="Yellow" status="Yes"/>
                <object objectId="897" objectLevel="Purple" status="Yes"/>
              </objects2>
            </program>
          </programs>
        </function>
      </functions>
    </description>
  </descriptions>
</info>
```

I want my `csv` to look something like this,

```
Header:
info_ABC,description_id,description_name,function_id,program_name,objectId,objectLevel,status

Data:
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,111,Green,Yes
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,222,Blue,No
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,333,Red,Maybe
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,444,Yellow,Yes
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,555,Purple,Yes
info_ABC,1,Test1,456,Xml5CSV,666,Green,Yes
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,777,Blue,No
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,888,Red,Maybe
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,999,Yellow,Yes
info_ABC,1,Test1,123,Xml2CSV,897,Purple,Yes
```

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the leaf `<object>` elements using `<xsl:for-each select="//object">`, and within the loop, access the ancestor attributes using, for example, `<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::function/@functionId"/>`

(By the way, you didn't say which part of the task you are having difficulty with, so I had to guess.)

Comment: Hey @Michael Kay, I was having issue creating a whole .xsl file in the first place

Comment: I am looking for the xsl code which would give me the above csv result

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking questions and getting answers, not for getting people to write your code for you. If you have a specific problem writing the code, please raise a new question.